# Which algorithim does Kubernetes use to assign pods to nodes?

Tags: algorithm, kubernetes, dynamic-programming, graph-algorithm, hungarian-algorithm

This is more of cost estimation question than how to use features like node affinity.

So basically there are `m` pods with some constraints like:

- each pod of specific `Deployments` / `StatefulSets` should be on a different kubernetes node
- pods of specific `Deployments` / `StatefulSets` should be balanced over 3 availability zones

Now, I want to find how many nodes (all same types) I will need to host given set of `Deployments` / `StatefulSets`.

I first thought this of more like an assignment problem to be solved using Hungarian Algorithim but this seems much more complex in term like multi dimensional constraints.

Comment: Is your problem now resolved?

Comment: not yet, this seems to be MRGAP problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By my knowledge the algorithm used by default by the kube-scheduler is described on github [here](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/opa-kube-scheduler/blob/master/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/docs/devel/scheduler_algorithm.md).

It explains how it works. It first filters nodes that do not meet the requirements of the pods, e.g. resource requests > available resources on nodes, affinity etc.

Then uses a ranking algorithm to determine the best fitting node. For deeper insights on the

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes assigns the pods based on the many constraints like

- Resource requirement
- Resource existence (Node capacity)
- Node selectors if any or Affinity rules
- Weight of Affinity rules

This is good article for same : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/kube-scheduler/

Also : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/

i would suggest to read the : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/

Answer (score 1):

In reference to the very good answer of user [Harsh Manvar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5525824/harsh-manvar), I will add a few more information from myself. This topic was covered in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/kube-scheduler/), as described by my predecessor. Besides her, you can find very good materials [here](https://www.magalix.com/blog/kubernetes-scheduler-101):

> **What Happens When You Create a Pod On a Kubernetes Cluster?**
> In a matter of seconds, the Pod is up and running on one of the cluster nodes. However, a lot has happened within those seconds. Let’s see:
>
> 1. While scanning the API server (which it is continuously doing), the Kubernetes Scheduler detects that there is a new Pod without a nodeName parameter. The nodeName is what shows which node should be owning this Pod.
> 2. The Scheduler selects a suitable node for this Pod and updates the Pod definition with the node name (though the nodeName parameter).
> 3. The kubelet on the chosen node is notified that there is a pod that is pending execution.
> 4. The kubelet executes the Pod, and the latter starts running on the node.

You can also find a [tutorial](https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/getting-started-with-kubernetes-%7C-scheduling-process-and-scheduler-algorithms_596299) about Scheduling Process and Scheduler Algorithms.